# Getting the id of a spinner

Tags: android

I have 2 spinners in an Activity, which take their data from the same Resource (xml string array).
Code is like this:

```
Spinner spinnerFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from_to);
Spinner spinnerTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from_to);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.length_from_to, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerFrom.setAdapter(adapter);
spinnerTo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But now in the

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
}
```

method, I get the correct values fom the spinners when I test it e.g. with a toast, but couldn't manage to know, from what of these two spinners the value comes from. I tried it with different parent-methods, but didn't help.

May you give me a hint, please?

Thanks much in forward.

Martin

Comment: both spinners use the `R.id.spinner_from_to`. are you sure that's correct?

Comment: I guess yes, because both just need the same values.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right, the id's are different, but because Im not on my PC anymore I wrote that wrong from my remind,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `android:tag` value to each spinner in the xml. Then use `view.getTag()` to in the `onItemSelected()` to get tag, enabling you to see from which one it was called.

Comment: However, this is probably not the optimal way to do it. You should perhaps assign each spinner a unique id then use those values

Comment: Thanks, abforce and howdoidothis. Ill try both solutions tommorow. Sounds very compromising!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `view.getId()`.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
    int pos, long id) {

    int id = parent.getId();
}
```

And with regard to the ID you've gotten decide what each item should do.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have same id for both the ‍`spinners R.id.spinner_from_to‍‍`.
Anyway... In order to get id of the spinner you can use

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
int pos, long id) {

    int id = parent.getId();
}
```